# Cython and cross-compilation

Tags: c, gcc, cross-compiling, cython, mingw32

I have a file `test.pyx` and a `test.c` generated by `$ cython test.pyx`. I want to create a shared object `test.so` with *gcc* so that I can import it into Python. Compilation for linux x86-64 with

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -I /usr/include/python2.7 -shared -o test.so test.c
```

Terminates successfully.

I want to compile the same file to a `.dll` for windows with `mingw32`. However when I attempt to execute

```
i586-mingw32msvc-gcc -Wall -fPIC -I /usr/include/python2.7 -shared -o test.dll test.c
```

I get this error:

```
test.c:1: warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent)
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:58,
                 from test.c:16:
/usr/include/python2.7/pyport.h:338:24: error: sys/select.h: No such file or directory
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: [This link may help you.](http://www.johnstowers.co.nz/blog/tag/mingw.html)

Comment: @MaR1oC try adding `-Ipath_to_sys_folder` in your command line...

Answer (score -1):

You do this with it:

```
<your_compiler> <cython_generated_c_file> -o <your_outputfilename> -fPIE -lpython<python_version> 
<cflags> <ldflags>
```

To get cflags:

```
python-config --cflags
```

For ldflags:

```
python-config --ldflags
```