# How to cython x86_64 linux .so on aarch64 m1 macbook?

Tags: cython, apple-m1, arm64

I have aarch64 mac and need to deploy cython code to x86_64 linux server. Is there any flags or smth I missing?

Comment: Cross-compilation of Cython modules has been asked about a number of times, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48518055/cross-compile-extension-on-linux-for-windows, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52987784/elegant-cross-platform-cython-module-compilation, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25012787/cython-and-cross-compilation. There isn't really a good solution, and you'd be much better just doing it in a virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have tried to do it in ubuntu docker container but still got aarch64 .so's. Is there difference in vm vs docker?